# SQL JOIN on column equalling either of two colums

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join two tables on one field `login_username` equalling either `user_username` or `user_email`.

I've tried this but it just doesn't work, it loops.

```
JOIN users ON login_username = user_username OR login_username = user_email
```

Is it possible to do this or do I need to do two seperate joins?

Comment: "doesn't work, it loops".  Please elaborate.

Comment: also provide your table stucture and the desired output

Comment: Apologies! I mean it just stays stuck on running the query.

Comment: I reckon user_email isn't indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any boolean condition other than `and` is a performance killer for `join`s.

I would suggest:

```
select . . .
from t left join
     users un
     on t.login_username = un.user_username left join
     users ue
     on t.login_username = ue.user_email
```

You do need to adjust the `select` clause to choose the non-null value, typically using `coalesce()` on whatever columns you are interested in.